# Binary matrices with equal rowsum and equal columnsum

Tags: matrices, binary

Is it possible that two distinct (0,1)-matrices, otherwise binary matrices, have same rowsum vector and same columnsum vector?

If so, which is smallest possible example?

Comment: Isn't there an obvious pair of $2\times 2$ matrices (one of them being an identity)?

Answer (score 1):

Take any pair of distinct permutation matrices of any dimension, the smallest being $2x2$.